# How to configure global transactionmanager in spring-boot with atomikos and hikari

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, distributed-transactions

This i my database configuration and app.properties

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.two")
    public HikariConfig hikariConfig2() {
        return new HikariConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource2() {
        HikariDataSource hds = new HikariDataSource(new hikariConfig2());
        return hds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource2());
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.one")
    public HikariConfig hikariConfig2() {
        return new HikariConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource1() {
        HikariDataSource hds = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig1());
        return hds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource1());
    }

}
```

and

```
datasource.one.jdbc-url=...
datasource.one.username=...
datasource.one.password=...
datasource.one.driver-class-name=...

datasource.two.jdbcUrl=...
datasource.two.username=...
datasource.two.password=...
datasource.two.driver-class-name=...
```

How should I create global transaction manager which will support two phase commit. I want to run this app inside docker with Tomcat so no JavaEE.
Also no hibernate. I am using [sql-processor](https://github.com/hudec/sql-processor) with spring-stack:

**PS:** In some very old [article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html?page=2) I found this but idk if it rigth sollution

```
@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager tm1() {
    DataSourceTransactionManager txm = new DataSourceTransactionManager(refDataSource());
    return txm;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager tm2() {
    DataSourceTransactionManager txm = new DataSourceTransactionManager(logDataSource());
    return txm;
}


@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Throwable {
    return new ChainedTransactionManager(tm1(), tm2());

}
```

Comment: By just including the `spring-boot-starter-atomikos`... See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html#boot-features-jta-atomikos. It will automatically be configured. The only thing you might need to do is wrap your `DataSource` in an `AtomikosDataSourceBean` for it to auto-register with Atomikos. Everything else will be done automatically.

Comment: and how should I wrap hikari ds into AtomikosDataSourceBean ?

Comment: By creating a `AtomikosDataSourceBean` and set the `DataSource` into it.  However I doubt it will work as you would need XA capable datasources and AFAIK Hikari isn't XA capable and as such it won't work.